# c# fill listview with data from sql

Tags: c#, sql, listview

I have a winform app in c# which loads items from `comboboxes` to a `listview` based on relations between them. 
That part works fine.
Now the simpler part I can't get to work, when I load the form I want the listbox to display all results, and only if the user wants he can filter with the comboboxes. 
How can i accomplish that.
The simple explanation is:
How can i load items to a listview on formload?
I tried several ways but wouldn´t work.
I removed some parts of code to shorten the post.
The code i have is:

```
public test()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}  
private void test_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter("select distinct desempenho from vidros", con);
    DataTable DTT = new DataTable();
    SDA.Fill(DTT);
    desempenho.Items.Clear();
    foreach (DataRow ROW in DTT.Rows)
    {
        desempenho.Items.Add(ROW["desempenho"].ToString());
    }
    SqlDataAdapter SDA2 = new SqlDataAdapter("select distinct valu from vidros", con);
    DataTable DTT2 = new DataTable();
    SDA2.Fill(DTT2);
    valu.Items.Clear();
    foreach (DataRow ROW in DTT2.Rows)
    {
        valu.Items.Add(ROW["valu"].ToString());
    }
    SqlDataAdapter SDA3 = new SqlDataAdapter("select distinct fs from vidros", con);
    DataTable DTT3 = new DataTable();
    SDA3.Fill(DTT3);
    fsolar.Items.Clear();
    foreach (DataRow ROW in DTT3.Rows)
    {
        fsolar.Items.Add(ROW["fs"].ToString());
    }
    SqlDataAdapter SDA4 = new SqlDataAdapter("select distinct sel from vidros", con);
    DataTable DTT4 = new DataTable();
    SDA4.Fill(DTT4);
    select.Items.Clear();
    foreach (DataRow ROW in DTT4.Rows)
    {
        select.Items.Add(ROW["sel"].ToString());
    }
    SqlDataAdapter SDA5 = new SqlDataAdapter("select distinct compo from vidros", con);
    DataTable DTT5 = new DataTable();
    SDA5.Fill(DTT5);
    select.Items.Clear();
    foreach (DataRow ROW in DTT5.Rows)
    {
        compo.Items.Add(ROW["compo"].ToString());
    }
    SqlDataAdapter SDA6 = new SqlDataAdapter("select distinct sel from vidros", con);
    DataTable DTT6 = new DataTable();
    SDA6.Fill(DTT6);
    select.Items.Clear();
    foreach (DataRow ROW in DTT6.Rows)
    {
        select.Items.Add(ROW["sel"].ToString());
    }
}
private void compo_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FillData();
}
private void select_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FillData();
}
private void fsolar_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FillData();
}
private void valu_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FillData();
}
private void desempenho_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FillData();
}
 string query = "select [desc],[enchimento],[compo] from vidros where 1=1 ";
            string queryWhere = "";
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;

            if (combo1value != "")
            {
                queryWhere += " and desempenho = @emp ";
                sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@emp", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = combo1value;
            }
            if (combo2value != "")
            {
                queryWhere += " and valu = @emp2 ";
                sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@emp2", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = combo2value;
            }
            if (combo3value != "")
            {
                queryWhere += " and fs = @emp3 ";
                sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@emp3", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = combo3value;
            }
            if (combo4value != "")
            {
                queryWhere += " and sel = @emp4 ";
                sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@emp4", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = combo4value;
            }
            if (combo5value != "")
            {
                queryWhere += " and compo = @emp5 ";
                sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@emp5", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = combo5value;
            }

            sda.SelectCommand.CommandText = query + queryWhere;

            DataTable DTT = new DataTable();

            sda.Fill(DTT);
            listView1.Items.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < DTT.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DataRow dr = DTT.Rows[i];
                ListViewItem listitem = new ListViewItem(dr["desc"].ToString());
                listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["enchimento"].ToString());
                listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["compo"].ToString());
                listView1.Items.Add(listitem);
            }
```

...
Thanks in advance

Comment: please expand on "won't work"... exception, not desired behavior (which is?), example of expected output. code looks ok at first glance.

Comment: the calling code would be the interesting part: if the combo box values are initially the empty string, and the code that you show gets executed (event handler?), all should work as expected.

Comment: @dlatikay hy, thanks for the help.the code works but i want the listview to appear filled from the beginning and not only when the user selects and item on a combobox. i tried to change the position of the code and other solutions but no sucess.

Comment: @dlatikay ill edit the post with the full code

Comment: @dlatikay post your answer ill mark it. thanks for the help